# How do I map to existing instances using AutoMapper's new API?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, automapper

In the previous API I could do:

```
AutoMapper.Mapper.Map(sourceObject, destinationObject);
```

But, what about in the recent one? (AutoMapper 4.2+)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Configuration:

```
public class MyProfile : AutoMapper.Profile
{
    protected override void Configure()
    {
        CreateMap<SourceClass, DestClass>();
    }
}
```

constructor (for example, or other place in your code) of your class

```
        var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.AddProfile<MyProfile>());
        mapper = config.CreateMapper();
```

OR simple:

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
    cfg.CreateMap<SourceClass, DestClass>();
});
```

(but with profile you can reuse this code in different places)

using

```
        DestClass destObject = mapper.Map<DestClass>(sourceObject);
```

look at https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Configuration

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. Do I need to inherit from AutoMapper.Profile for this to work?

Comment: BTW, in which part of the code do I specify the **existing** object?

Comment: @JoseA "sourceObject" is the existing object, which you want to "convert" (copy properties) to destObject

Comment: Thanks a bunch man! The last line code you've just put **creates a new map**. To map to an existing object, it will be: *mapper.Map(fromObject, toObject)*. instead of mapper.Map<DestClass>(sourceObject)

Comment: @JoseA, you are wrong, both method map to an existing object :)